# Linked library is broken after collection rename

Tags: linked-data, collections

I created collections in Prop.blend and named them **'prop 1'**, **'prop 2'**, **'prop 3'**, **'prop 4'** and linked to Master.blend.
This works fine.

Over time, many collections were added to Prop.blend.
And I realized that they can be classified as static and dynamic.
Now I want to give the collections a new rule name to further organize the Prop.blend file.
The new names are **'st.prop 1'**, **'st.prop 2'**, **'dyn.prop 1'**, **'dyn.prop 2'**.

Save Prop.blend and open Master.blend again.
The link to the collection is broken.
I have already renamed many collections and there are no backups.
How can I solve this situation?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). I'm afraid you'll need to relink them all manually. However, if you store all collections inside one .blend (in multiple scenes) the links get updated automatically, which is nice.

Comment: @JachymMichal could you please ellaborate how to relink them? Notably, if you applied a Library Override, do you need to completely remove your object and redo all overwrite manually?

Comment: Hello @tobias :-). Please post your comment as a new question. This thread is almost a year old, and Blender might've got some changes in this regard.

Comment: Oh I just noticed you already did :). Nevermind then.

Comment: My new question is a bit different tough. But for me the whole point of Stack Exchange is to avoid to create many similar questions to centralize information. If someone knows how to do that, I guess they should update this thread.